# How to truncate all logfiles?

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, log

can anybody give me a solution to truncate all logfile in `/var/log/` directory?

and a question just for knowledge, is it a good idea or not?

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGDIR="/var/log"
for logfile in $(ls $LOGDIR/*log)
do
  truncate -s 0 $logfile
done
```

Comment: It's NOT a good idea - `/var/log` is where the system puts messages you might need later. Ubuntu has encountered the problem before. Read `man 8 logrotate;man logrotate.conf`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

try this:

`truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log`

EDIT:

if you want to do this more than once you should use `logrotate` to handle your logs. Usually it's installed in ubuntu. Have a look at `man logrotate` (or if you do not have it installed look at [the online manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/logrotate.8.html) or install it with `sudo apt-get install logrotate`)

from the manpage:

> logrotate  is  designed to ease administration of systems that
>   generate
>          large numbers of log files.  It allows automatic rotation, compression,
>          removal, and mailing of log files.  Each log file may be handled daily,
>          weekly, monthly, or when it grows too large.

Comment: also you can empty them by using 
echo "" > *log

Answer (score 11):

If you want to clear *all* your log files, not just those in the first-level log folder, you could use:

```
shopt -s globstar                  # if needed
truncate -s 0 /var/log/*.log       # first-level logs
truncate -s 0 /var/log/**/*.log    # nested folders, like /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Noting that if you already have `logrotate` running, you'll need to clear out the rotated `.gz` logs as well:

```
find /var/log -type f -name '*.[0-99].gz' -exec rm {} +
```

A valid use for this could be building a VM appliance container for distribution, for example.

You should *not* need to do this as part of routine maintenance: as D-E-N quite correctly suggested, use `logrotate` for that.

Answer (score 3):

As follow up to [@D-E-N](https://askubuntu.com/users/138119/d-e-n) answer

This will find all log files in `/var/log` and truncate them to 0 bytes.

```
find /var/log -type f -iname '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 truncate -s0
```

Comment: I would use `*.log*` instead but I'm not sure if it's 100% safe, so I haven't included it in the answer. Because there are files like `dovecot.log-20180930` and `dovecot.log-20180923.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

There's couple methods to fully truncating a file, generally applicable to most POSIX-compliant OS. Most common that you'll see with shell scripting is something like `true > file.txt` or `: > file.txt` ( and in case of `bash` shell, `>` redirection alone is sufficient ). That's due to the way how `>` opens files via `open()` or [`openat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html) syscall with `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC` flags - that reads write-only OR create if filename doesn't exist, OR truncate existing filename.

With that in mind, we can implement something like that in C ourselves:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc == 2){
        int fd = open(argv[1],O_TRUNC);
        close(fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Name the file that stores this code as `trunc.c` and compile that with `gcc trunc.c -o trunc`, and you have yourself a small utility that will truncate a filename argument it's provided as in `trunc ./foobar.txt`. Of course, this code doesn't do other checks, it only truncates first positional parameter. I'll leave it up to the readers to figure out how to deal with more than one positional parameter. On side note, there is [`truncate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/truncate.html) syscall which we could use as well, and truncate a file to variable length.

Now, if you are not a fan of C, Python might be easier for you. `open()` command operates on the same principle in Python - opening file for writing and truncating if filename exists. Thus we can do

```
python -c 'import sys;open(sys.argv[1],"w").close()' passwd.copy
```

As for finding all `.log` files, that's been covered in other answers already - use `*` glob or extended glob in `bash`. There's also `find -type f -name "*.log"` , which has `-exec` flag for running commands (in this particular case `sh -c ''` to take advantage of `>` because `>` is a shell operator and not an external executable). Thus you can do

```
find /var/log -type f -name "*.log" -exec sh -c 'true > "$1"' sh {} \;
```

It's also worth noting that log files in directory such as `/var/log` often are rotated by logrotate service, so there will be filenames such as `/var/log/service.log`, `/var/log/service.log.1`, etc , so you may want to use `*.log.[1-9]` pattern instead

---

Among other things, we can copy `/dev/null` into the desired file. Oddly enough, even though `/dev/null` is a special character  device type of file, when you copy that elsewhere the result is empty regular file, at least with GNU `cp`. Thus we can do

```
cp /dev/null foo.txt
```

or

```
dd if=/dev/null of=foo.txt
```

Other suggested reading:

- [What's the difference between > and >>](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067048/295286)
- [Python's open function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)
- [How to clean log file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92384/85039)
- [Empty contents of a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88808/85039)

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to rotate the logs in /var/logs to rotate with logrotate functionality but not whenever we wish to do. System logs will be printed her and they will be handy to debug any failures.

If it is a requirement not to use logrotate, then options can be explored. Though truncate is easy option in few flavors of unix system this command is not available readily, need to be installed.If not allowed to install the new command then below loop can be used.

```
for logfile $(ls /path/*.log)
do 
  cat /dev/null > $logfile
done
```

Comment: [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29): _Don't write for loops that way._ Use `for logfile in /path/*.log` instead.