# What's is the difference between ">" and ">>" in shell command?

Tags: command-line

Could someone explain to me the difference between `>` and `>>` when using shell commands?

Example:

```
ps -aux > log
ps -aux >> log
```

It seems the result is the same either way.

Comment: For additional info on some of the bash operators , refer also to [What's the difference between <<, <<< and < < in bash?](http://askubuntu.com/q/678915/295286)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`>` is used to overwrite (“*[clobber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering)*”) a file and `>>` is used to append to a file.

Thus, when you use `ps aux > file`, the output of `ps aux` will be written to `file` and if a file named `file` was already present, its contents will be overwritten.

And if you use `ps aux >> file`, the output of `ps aux` will be written to `file` and if the file named `file` was already present, the file will now contain its previous contents and also the contents of `ps aux`, written after its older contents of `file`.

Answer (score 18):

if you write in terminal

```
ps aux > log
```

It will put the output of `ps aux` to log named file.

then if you put

```
ps aux >> log
```

then the next output will be appended below the first. if you put only one `>` it will overwrite the previous file.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `>>` appends, `>` always overwrites/destroys the previous content.

```
ps -aux > log
```

is the same as

```
rm log 2>/dev/null
ps -aux >> log
```

On Wintel it is the same for `.bat`, `.cmd` and `.ps1` scripts too; common heritage, common sense.

Answer (score 4):

Most important difference is that `>` makes shell open a file or file-like object with `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC` flags - the file will be created or truncated if it exists, while `>>` opens file with `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND` flags - file will be created or appended to if it exists. This is evident if you trace system calls, for example with

```
$ strace -e open,dup2 bash -c 'true >> /dev/null'
...
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1
```

And with

```
$ strace -e open,dup2 bash -c 'true > /dev/null'
...
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Notice that in both cases the file descriptor of the open file is duplicated onto file descriptor 1 ( stdout ) of the command, and that will be inherited by whatever command the shell forks.