# how to use output redirection to demonstrate what TREE does

Tags: command-line, redirect

This is a question I found in a test:

> Run tree from your home directory.
>   Explain and demonstrate what it does.
>   Use output redirection to do this.

I don't understand the output redirection part. Could you explain it to me please?

Comment: This http://askubuntu.com/q/382793/295286  and this http://askubuntu.com/a/678919/295286 may be useful

Comment: This question got PROTECTED. I don't even.

Answer (score 2):

**tree** : `tree` lists the contents of directories in a tree-like format. It's a really neat and useful program you can use at the command line to view the structure of your file system.

**output redirection** means store command output somewhere else other than simple printing on  terminal . if you want to store `tree` command output in file then use command

```
tree > test
```

that will redirect output to this file. this command will create a file `test` and if this already exits then it will replace it't content  with `tree` command output.
if you don't want to replace and just want to append then use command

```
tree >> test
```

this will append output of `tree` command to file `test`. you can give full path of file where you want to store output.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in that context output redirection = *redirection of standard output (`stdout`) to a regular file*.

```
tree >tree_output.txt
```

However output redirection in general means redirection of one of the default output streams (standard output (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`), normally both directed to the terminal) to anything that can be considered a file (regular file, `stderr` if `stdout` is the stream in question, `stdout` if `stderr` is the stream in question, pipe, named pipe (FIFO), block device, character device ...), and it's not limited to the redirection of standard output (`stdout`) to a regular file like in the example.

So there are lots of possible output redirections;

Assuming for the sake of brevity that the output in question is the standard output (`stdout`), these are the most common possible redirections:

- `echo foo >file`: `stdout` is redirected to a regular file;
- `echo foo >&2`: `stdout` is redirected to `stderr`;
- `echo foo | cat`: `stdout` is redirected to a pipe;
- `mkfifo fifo && echo foo >fifo`: `stdout` is redirected to a named pipe (FIFO);
- `echo foo >/dev/sdX`: `stdout` is redirected to a block device (**DON'T DO THAT - it could do nothing but messing up the partition table of the block device in question**);

More esoteric redirections:

- `echo foo >/dev/tty`: `stdout` is redirected to a character device, which happens to be the current pseudo-terminal;
- Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, logging in, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, running `echo foo>/dev/tty1` and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>; `stdout` is redirected to a character device, which happens to be the first pseudo-terminal;

So output redirection in general means redirection of one of the default output streams (standard output (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`), normally both directed to the terminal) to anything that can be considered a file;

In order to run `tree` using output redirection (and actually showing something on the terminal) there are multiple ways:

- `tree >tree_output.txt && cat tree_output.txt`: runs `tree` redirecting `stdout` to a regular file;
- `tree >&2`: runs `tree` redirecting `stdout` to `stderr`;
- `tree | cat`: runs `tree` redirecting `stdout` to a pipe;
- `mkfifo fifo && tree >fifo`: runs `tree` redirecting `stdout` to a named pipe;
- `tree >/dev/tty`: runs `tree` redirecting `stdout` to a character device (the current pseudo-terminal);
- Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, logging in, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, running `echo foo>/dev/tty1` and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>`tree >/dev/tty1`: runs `tree` redirecting `stdout` to a character device (the first pseudo-terminal);